# Is it legal to use Youtube Data API to create youtube-like app that aggregrate youtube videos from any channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

i'm planning to create some app that use youtube-api.

Is it legal to use Youtube Data API to create youtube-like app that aggregrate youtube videos from any channel? even it is not my channel or my video? Can I (legally) monetize those app with Admob?

Comment: apple might reject your app under 5.2 Intellectual Property ref link ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256829/my-flutter-app-got-reject-from-apple-review-stating-this-5-2-intellectual-proper

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is answered in the first paragraph of the [YouTube API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms).

### 1. Is it legal to use Youtube Data API to create youtube-like app that aggregrate youtube videos from any channel?

The terms don't prohibit it, as long as the client is compliant with the ToS. So, **yes**, it is legal.

### 2. Can I (legally) monetize those app with Admob?

**It depends.**

> You agree not to use the YouTube API for any of the following commercial uses unless You obtain YouTube's prior written approval: [...] the sale of advertising, sponsorships, or promotions on any page of the API Client containing YouTube audiovisual content, unless other content not obtained from YouTube appears on the same page and is of sufficient value to be the basis for such sales.

I'm not an expert in law questions, but what this says (imho) is that you may advertise your application if it does not solely contain YouTube content. In other words, your application has to extend the functionality of https://youtube.com, not recreate it.

In any case, you may not block or in any way alter in-player ads.

### Conclusion

Based on the short concept of your app you posted in the question, I would say:

1. You may build "youtube-like app that aggregrate youtube videos from any channel", **but**
2. you **may not advertise** it, since it does not feature original content.

Comment: Problem is Youtube shuts down inadvertitely your API with their policy par. "Too similar to Youtube" or even better "Doesn't add significant value compared to Youtube"

Answer (score 0):

if you plan to publish this on app store please review the [IOS Guide Lines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#intellectual-property)

> 5.2.3 Audio/Video Downloading: Apps should not facilitate illegal file sharing or include the ability to save, convert, or download media
> from third-party sources (e.g. Apple Music, YouTube, SoundCloud,
> Vimeo, etc.) without explicit authorization from those sources.
> Streaming of audio/video content may also violate Terms of Use, so be
> sure to check before your app accesses those services. Documentation
> must be provided upon request.

[And this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256829/my-flutter-app-got-reject-from-apple-review-stating-this-5-2-intellectual-proper)