# My Flutter App got reject from Apple Review stating this 5.2 Intellectual Property (5.2.3)

Tags: flutter, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, appstore-approval

**My App got reject from Apple Review stating this  (AUG/2020)**

I'm using the ***youtube data api v3*** to get the popular videos by
country and  display as a list in the app (App built using Flutter &
include other content tabs too). each list ***item displaying only the
title, description, thumbnail image and upload date***. when click on
list item to stream the video I launch in youtube app. (no steaming
in my app). but apple reject my app stating "Guideline 5.2.3"

> [Guideline 5.2.3 - Legal](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#intellectual-property)
>
> 5.2.3 Audio/Video Downloading: Apps should not facilitate illegal file sharing or include the ability to save, convert, or download media
> from third-party sources (e.g. Apple Music, YouTube, SoundCloud,
> Vimeo, etc.) without explicit authorization from those sources.
> Streaming of audio/video content may also violate Terms of Use, so be
> sure to check before your app accesses those services. Documentation
> must be provided upon request.
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please attach documentary evidence in the App
> Review Information section in App Store Connect evidencing that you
> have all necessary rights or permissions to the third-party audio or
> video streaming, catalogs, and discovery services in your app.

I'm not sure which document to upload to pass the apple review or how to resolve this issue.

also In my app i'm not streaming any videos, only redirecting to youtube app. I'm not sure it's violate Terms of Use,

Thanks.

check this on apple [developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/111383)

Comment: Perhaps an app that simply shows a list in apple will be rejected. Probably, other web-enabled apps will be rejected. If you ask the reason for rejection in detail, we may answer it.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this "Perhaps an app that simply shows a list in apple will be rejected. Probably, other web-enabled apps will be rejected."

Comment: If sufficient service is available on the web, the app will be rejected. You need to add functionality using push or widgets.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "push or widgets", but  app also include a push notification service to notify the user about new content.

Comment: Using Youtube api does not bring copyright to Youtube videos. Those who are linked to YouTube video have the copyright. Perhaps, for this reason, it was answered that the 5.2.3 guidelines were not followed.

Comment: is it a violation of youtube TOS if the app showing youtube video list and redirecting to youtube app to stream the content? if i want to do such a thing do i need to provide documents to app store ?

Comment: Perhaps, yes You will have to prove that the YouTube video linked to Google is your video.

Comment: youtube videos i not belong to me i'm creating a video index  using "you-tube data apiv3" and displaying on my app to stream the video i redirect user to youtube app.

Comment: My Flutter app got rejected as well because of the same things. YouTube allows to embed videos on 3rd party sites / apps if "Allow embedding" is set to Yes on the YouTube video, but Apple still rejecting apps even if these apps only displaying the thumbnails of these videos from YouTube.  I have the same app in the Google Play and I don't have any issues with these thing, but on iOS I decided to remove this functionality for now - so I don't display thumbnails and I don't allow to play YouTube videos inside my app via YouTube IFrame API. if I find how to make Apple happy, I will let you know

Comment: Just got my app rejected for downloading media as well. Did you manage to solve this @Sam

Answer (score 2):

I found this https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies-guide article and in this article I found that it is possible to apply for an API Compliance Audit via this form https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form. Then the result of this audit can be attached to App Review Information section in order to provide confirmation for Apple that app doesn't violate Terms of Use.